# Function returns "query has no destination for result data"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function that will effectively function as an UPSERT and return either 0 for a successful UPDATE or the id of the new record for a successful INSERT. While the function will create successfully, I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
query has no destination for result data
```

I'm running it this way (data obviously masked):

```
select public.mergeaddress(0, 2, 'XXX XX XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XX', 'XXXXX', true, true, -XXX.XXXXXX, XX.XXXXXXX);
```

I know I must be missing something obvious here. Any thoughts?

```
CREATE FUNCTION mergeAddress(integer, integer, varchar, varchar, varchar, varchar, boolean, boolean, float, float) RETURNS integer AS

$$

DECLARE new_id integer;

BEGIN
    LOOP
        UPDATE users_addresses SET users_id = $2, address_street = $3, address_city = $4, address_state = $5, address_zip = $6, is_private = $7, is_default = $8, long = $9, lat = $10 WHERE id = $1 RETURNING id;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN 0;
        END IF;
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO users_addresses VALUES (DEFAULT, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING id INTO new_id;
            RETURN new_id;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
         -- Restart the loop
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that your UPDATE:

```
UPDATE users_addresses ... RETURNING id;
```

has a RETURNING but you don't tell it where that return value should go. That's the query that doesn't have a destination for the result. If you want the `id` then you'll need to put it somewhere:

```
UPDATE users_addresses ... RETURNING id INTO somewhere;
-- -------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You would of course use a real variable name and properly declare it, `somewhere` is just for illustrative purposes.

Or, since you don't care what the `id` the UPDATE finds is, just ditch the `RETURNING id` and only bother with the `found` special variable:

```
UPDATE users_addresses SET ... WHERE id = $1;
IF found THEN
    RETURN 0;
END IF;
-- ...
```

Comment: D'oh! All the more reason to proofread what I'm doing, right? Thanks!